# Can I use same Foreign key for different tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

Suppose I am making a voting system for teachers and want to make voting_id a primary key for two tables teachers and senior teachers and making voting_id a single foreign key for both the tables in my new table Voters can I make If I can then HOW?

Comment: No you cannot, not in the strict sense of "foreign key referential constraint". Your example isn't that great either, because teachers and senior teachers should be in the same table, with possibly a surrogate table with additional data (columns) for senior tables.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to have separate tables for teachers and senior teachers?  It seems highly likely that those are really the same entity that should be modeled with a single `teacher` table that has a `senior_teacher` attribute.  You would then create a `voter` table with a `teacher_id` column that refers to the `teacher_id` primary key in the `teacher` table.  It doesn't make sense for the primary key of the `teacher` table to be `voter_id` rather than `teacher_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I would model it differently. Teacher can have N votes(1:N relation). So the votes table has teacher_id, probably a grade and timestamp. I would put teacher and senior teacher in the same table and add a type column to it(senior or normal), because senior teacher is just an extended type of a teacher.

Voting_id can't be primary key because it identifies vote not the teacher. Also you would have collisions because teacher and senior teacher can have the same primary id if they are in two seperate tables.